Issues with Mocking S3 Multipart Upload After Migrating from AWS SDK v2 to v3
I'm trying to run a test. It worked fine with AWS SDK v2, but after migrating to v3 using codemod,I'm facing issues.
This is my index.spec.js to test the test using mocha and sinon. My test is getting failed with error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'requestHandler')
This is my index.spec.js
const TEST_FILE_CONTENT={data:'test-data'}
const s3Stub=sinon.stub();
describe('upload',()=>{

it('should upload object from S3', async()=>{

const inputStream = new Readable({

read:()=>{

inputStream.push(JSON.stringify(TEST FILE CONTENT));

inputStream.push(null);
}
});

s3Stub.prototype.upload.returns({

promise: sinon.stub().resolves(),

on: sinon.stub()
});

 await s3Client.upload({key: TEST_KEY, data: inputStream }); 
 expect(s3Stub.prototype.upload.callCount).to.eql(1); 
 expect(s3Stub.prototype.upload.args[0][0]).to.containSubset({ 
Bucket: process.env.ENV_BUCKET,
 Key: TEST_KEY
})
});

This is my index.js
import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";
import { S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { PassThrough } from "stream";
import moment from "moment";

interface UploadParams {
  key: string;
  data: PassThrough;
  compressData?: boolean;
  expiryDays?: number;
  retry?: number;
}

class S3Client {
  private s3: S3;

  constructor(s3Client: S3) {
    this.s3 = s3Client;
  }

  async upload({
    key,
    data,
    compressData = false,
    expiryDays = 0,
    retry = 0
  }: UploadParams): Promise<void> {
    arguments.notNull(key,'key');
    arguments.notNull(data,'data');

    const 
    isComplressionEnabled=env('COMPRESSION_ENABLED','true')=== 
    'true && compressData';

    const start = new Date().getTime();
    const partSize = 5242880;
    const queueSize = 20;
    const options = { partSize, queueSize };
    const params = {
      Bucket: "test-bucket-name",
      Key: key,
      Body: data.pipe(new PassThrough()),
      Expires: moment().add(1, "days").toISOString(),
      ACL: "private",
    };

    global.logger.debug(`Uploading stream of data to S3 with key 
    '${key}'`);

    const upload = new Upload({
      client: this.s3,
      params,
      ...options,
    });

    upload.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress) => {
      Metrics.logUploadStatus(progress);
      Metrics.logMemoryUsage();
    });

    try {
      await upload.done();
    } catch (error) {
      const msgPrefix = `Failure in 
      S3Uploader.upload(key=${key})`;

      if (retry < 3) {
        global.logger.debug(`${msgPrefix}. Retry attempt: 
      ${retry}`);
        await randomBackOff(retry);
        return this.upload({ key, data, compressData, 
      expiryDays, retry: retry + 1 });
      }

      const prependNewStacktrace = true;
      throw 
      UnifiedFailureInfo.fromFailureObject(error).addPrefix(
        msgPrefix,
        prependNewStacktrace
      );
    }

    const took = new Date().getTime() - start;
    global.logger.debug(
      `Finished S3 upload of data with key '${key}'. Took 
    ${took}ms`
    );
    Metrics.logMemoryUsage();
    return undefined;
  }
}

